# How to replace the <br /> tag within List<String> in java?

Tags: java, list

I m having a `List<String>` like this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Some elements in the list has `<br />` tags at the end of the string,
for example, when i print the above list, it gives me the following result

```
`[java, struts, php, ajax , javascript<br />, python, mysql, spring,<br />, hibernate, drupal<br />]`
```

I want to remove the the `<br />` at the end of each string in the List,

the code i have tried to replace the html tag is,

```
for(String s: list){
s.replace("<br />", "");
}
```

But that does not work..whats wrong with my code.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already reported by others, `String`s are immutable so any operation on them returns a *new* string.

Here's a solution working on the same `ArrayList`, without making a new one:

```
ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    it.set(it.next().replace("<br />", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable in Java. `String.replace()` does not change the string given as parameter. Instead, it returns a **new** String object, that you need to process (e.g. remove the original and add the new one to your list).

Answer (score 1):

`String` is not mutable. Invoking of most methods in `String` results in a new `String` being created

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s : list){
  newList.add(s.replace("<br />", ""));
}
```

Now the new list contains all previous values without the `<br/>`

Comment: Use `List<String>`, please! Teach people to use generics, it saves you casts later on and avoids programming errors.

Answer (score 1):

String are immutable so you must capture the result.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String s: list){
  newList.add(s.replace("<br />", ""));
}
```